# nextflow does not find all my python modules

Tags: python-3.x, import, nextflow

I am trying to make a Nextflow script that utilizes a python script. My python script imports a number of modules but within Nextflow python3 does not find two (cv2 and matplotlib) of 7 modules and crashes. If I call the script directly from bash it works fine. I would like to avoid creating a docker image to run this script.

```
Error executing process > 'grab_images (1)'

Caused by:
  Process `grab_images (1)` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  python3 --version
  echo 'processing image-1.npy'
  python3 /home/hq/cv_proj/k_means2.py image-1.npy

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  Python 3.7.3
  processing image-1.npy

Command error:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/hq/cv_proj/k_means2.py", line 5, in <module>
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Work dir:
  /home/hq/cv_proj/work/7f/b787c62ec420b2b5eb490603ef913f

Tip: you can replicate the issue by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `bash .command.run`
```

I think there is a path issue as modules like numpy, sys, re, time are successfully loaded. How can I fix?

Thanks in advance

*UPDATE*

To assist other who may have problems using python in nextflow scripts... Make sure your shebang is correct. I was using

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
```

instead of

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
```

Since all of my packages were installed with pip3 and I exclusively use python3 you need to have the right shebang.

Comment: do a `which python` in your process block and in your regular bash shell to ensure you are using the same python installation in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to avoid absolute paths to your script(s) in your process declarations. This section of the docs is worth taking some time to read: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#manage-dependencies, particularly the subsection on how to manage third party scripts:

> Any third party script that does not need to be compiled (Bash,
> Python, Perl, etc) can be included in the pipeline project repository,
> so that they are distributed with it.
>
> Grant the execute permission to these files and copy them into a
> folder named bin/ in the root directory of your project repository.
> Nextflow will automatically add this folder to the PATH environment
> variable, and the scripts will automatically be accessible in your
> pipeline without the need to specify an absolute path to invoke them.

Then the problem is how to manage your Python dependencies. You mentioned Docker is not an option. Is [Conda](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/conda.html) also not an option? The config for Conda might look something like:

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - conda-forge::matplotlib-base=3.4.3
  - conda-forge::numpy=1.21.2
  - conda-forge::opencv=4.5.2
```

Then if the above is in a file called `environment.yml`, create the environment with:

```
conda env create
```

See also the [best practices](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/conda.html#best-practices) for using Conda.

Comment: Thanks for the link I will take a read. I think my issue is that I am running nextflow scripts with sudo rather than myself. I installed the other modules with sudo pip3 and it worked. That is a gross solution though. I need to figure out how to get nextflow without elevated privileges. I have googled but no luck so far.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice Ah, yeah that'll be it. You definitely don't need to be root to run Nextflow :-)  All you need to install is `curl -s https://get.nextflow.io | bash` (as yourself), assuming you have Java 8 or later. Then just move the executable to somewhere in your $PATH. Also, instead of installing Python mods globally, it might be preferable to use a virtual env: `python -mvenv myenv`, activate it, then `pip install` your deps.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting `.nextflow/history.lock (Permission denied)`. Have you seen that before?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice Permission denied... where are you trying to run your Nextflow executable from? Did the test command run ok: `./nextflow run hello`?

Comment: If I run hello from my bare home directory it runs. If I try and run from a folder in my home directoy like `~/foo` using `~/nextflow run hello`. I get the history lock error.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice You could see that error if you don't have write permissions on `~/foo/.nextflow`. Check that you own it, or just blow it away and have Nextflow re-create it on your next run. It could be owned by root if you've been running Nextflow as root.

Comment: This worked, since I first ran as root it created all this infrastructure that I was not owner of and thus was blocking everything. Blowing it all away did the trick. Thank you!